# PHP - Preg Match Count Issues

Tags: php, count

So im trying to ocunt the amount of proxies in a **string** the issue is for everything I tried all thats outputting is `1` but it should be near like 150.

What I tried:

`preg_split('/(\/n)/',$proxies); count($preg_split_variable);`

`preg_match_all('/(\/n)/',$proxies) count($preg_match_all_variable);`

My code:

```
//Get the proxies from cUrl; Works fine.
foreach($un as $op2) {
    query("INSERT INTO proxies (proxy,last_grabbed,last_grabid,url) VALUES (:proxy,:last_grabbed,:last_grabid,:proxyurl)",array(":proxy"=>$op2,":last_grabbed"=>$date,":last_grabid"=>$grabid,":proxyurl"=>$proxyurl[0]['url']),'unfed_tools');
    $proxies .= $op2."\n";
}

//Count the amount of grabbed proxies; Doesnt work; Outputs 1 every time;
$proxycount = preg_match_all('/(\/n)/',$proxies);
count($proxycount);
```

I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't storing the number of found results. Also couldn't you just put a count in the foreach (if the only new lines are the ones you are putting into `$proxies` in the loop)?

Comment: Use `substr_count()` (Otherwise: RTM what `preg_match_all` returns)

Comment: @chris85 Wow, No idea how I didnt spot this...

Comment: `\/n` is not a newline. Perhaps you mean `\\n`?

Comment: @Rizier123 I would prefer to use preg_match_all.

Comment: @Phylogenesis \/n is \n the \/ makes the \ just format correctly in the eyes of regex And \\n isn't even a thing. Its \n

Comment: Ignoring the fact you could just use `$proxyCount++` in your loop, you use `\n` to separate the proxies in `$proxies`. You are then attempting to split on `/n`.

Comment: What about just `count(explode("\n",$string));`?

Comment: @chris85 Yup that works fine! Thanks! Make it an answe please.

Comment: @JohnButler You are completely wrong here: `\/n` is equals to `/n`; `\` is used to escape things. And if you want to use `\n` in your regex, use: `"\\n"` / `'\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `preg_match_all` doesn't give a count for a couple reasons. The first being you aren't capturing the found values. The second being `\n` is a newline not `/n`. You can see the difference here, https://regex101.com/r/jE2oS6/1.

So you could do

```
foreach($un as $op2) {
    query("INSERT INTO proxies (proxy,last_grabbed,last_grabid,url) VALUES (:proxy,:last_grabbed,:last_grabid,:proxyurl)",array(":proxy"=>$op2,":last_grabbed"=>$date,":last_grabid"=>$grabid,":proxyurl"=>$proxyurl[0]['url']),'unfed_tools');
    $proxies .= $op2."\n";
}

//Count the amount of grabbed proxies; Doesnt work; Outputs 1 every time;
preg_match_all('/(\n)/',$proxies, $proxycount);
count($proxycount[1]);
```

Another approach would be

```
count(explode("\n", $proxies));
```